# How can I append a dataframe and add a row with repeated measure column info within the same dataframe

Tags: r

So I need an idea of how I can duplicate several fields in a row of data in a df with the exception of the species (spec) and other length measures and append the df with that row of information and length.
len1 is the length of each specimen, but I need to convert each length measure to it's own row in the dataframe while duplicating the other measures (sal,DO,temp,mo,year) I can convert empty length fields to "." to help with coding I know, but any suggestion on a starting point or coding direction would be greatly appreciated.

I am just getting back into really using R for work now instead of grad school so I'm a little rusty, but getting there. First time using stackoverflow so apologize if I'm not following some norms.

Starting to get familiar with dplyr and reshape but any libraries or tutorials for something like this are greatly appreciated.

```
year    mo  temp    sal DO     spec len1 len2 len3
2019    1   15      7.2 8.31    ooo         
2019    1   15.5    5.2 8.75    atc 175     
2019    1   15.5    5.2 8.75    cfc 135 156 
2019    1   15.5    5.2 8.75    men 181 206 174
```

For the example data above trying to get to where the second length for cfc moves to len1 on a new row in the dataframe

```
year    mo  temp    sal DO     spec len1
2019    1   15.5    5.2 8.75    cfc 156
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `gather` from tidyr.  This converts the column name into a value in a new column.
For example assuming your data is in a dataframe called df

```
library(tidyverse)
df%>%
    gather( key = "sampleID",  # name for new column that will contain "NA, len1, len1,l1n2, etc)
            value = "length",  # name for new column that will contain length values
            len1:len3          # columns to include in the process
           )
```

At this point you could drop the "sampleID" column if you wish, for example with

```
df %>% select(-sampleID)
# or other equivalent approaches
select(df,-sampleID)  # same command using tidyr without the pipe
df$sampleID <- NULL   # base R approach
```

Comment: worked like a charm thank you. I also entered in a drop_na to remove the values that were empty.        df.1=df%>%
  gather(key='sampleID',value='lgt',len:len.9)%>%
  drop_na(lgt)%>%
  select(-sampleID,-X)%>%